# send mail to gmail inbox instead of spam by using php in smtp connection

Tags: php, email, inbox

I used the php mailing function to send mail.but my mails send to spam folder. I want to send my mail to inbox.How can I send mail to gmail inbox instead of spam by using php in smtp connection.

Comment: This isn't a problem with how the mail is being sent. Your mails will go into the spam folder if they look like spam. (*Are* they spam?)

Comment: There's some flag somewhere in GMail that's probably been raised by your testing efforts.  You can probably set something to indicate that your tests aren't spam.

Comment: What does the email itself look like? For example, what is the sender's address, the body, etc? The same thing can happen if you send mail using the unix mail command because the sender's address will be username@hostname or if you have a url such as localhost:1234 in the body and gmail doesn't like things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want us to tell you how to spam a mailbox with the Google genius detecting it's spam. Not happening.

However, if you are serious... Email applications look for spam if it looks like spam. Be sure to sent the proper settings in the email and don't look like a spammer with stuff like 'here is some text. Wait click this link'

AKA php has no power to override email filters.